# Alarm clock printing

Tags: python, datetime

I know there must be an easier way to write this but I'm stuck in over-complicating mindset instead of just following the Zen of Python. Please help me simplify this.

> Given a day of the week encoded as 0=Sun, 1=Mon, 2=Tue, ...6=Sat, and
>   a boolean indicating if we are on vacation, return a string of the
>   form "7:00" indicating when the alarm clock should ring. Weekdays, the
>   alarm should be "7:00" and on the weekend it should be "10:00". Unless
>   we are on vacation -- then on weekdays it should be "10:00" and
>   weekends it should be "off".
>
> ```
> alarm_clock(1, False) → '7:00'
> alarm_clock(5, False) → '7:00'
> alarm_clock(0, False) → '10:00'
> ```

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):

    weekend = "06"
    weekdays = "12345"
    if vacation:
        if str(day) in weekend:
            return "off"
        else:
            return "10:00"
    else:
        if str(day) in weekend:
            return "10:00"
        else:
            return "7:00"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it can get much simpler than this (Pythonic, easy to read, performance great enough to never be a bottleneck):

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
    weekend = int(day) in (0, 6)
    if weekend and vacation:
        return 'off'
    elif weekend or vacation:
        return '10:00'
    return '7:00'
```

---

I came up with this after creating a `weekend` boolean value and then checking the return values `alarm_clock` should have:

```
return_values = {
    # (weekend, vacation): Return value,
    (True, True): 'off',
    (True, False): '10:00',
    (False, True): '10:00',
    (False, False): '7:00'
}
```

As you can see, if both are True (`if weekend and vacation:`), we should return `'off'`, and if one of them is True (`if weekend or vacation:`), we should return `10:00` regardless of which one. Else return `7:00`

Comment: I see you omitted the word "else", is that Pythonic?

Comment: @noob81 That's everyone's personal preference, but it's often considered more pythonic to emit the "else"

Comment: @noob81 Actually, I take that back. It's just everyone's personal preference, there's absolutely no guidelines to whether you should emit it or not. Often depends on the situation :)

Answer (score 7):

1. You don't use weekdays.
2. You can have two return statements. (Shown below).

This keeps the same logic, it just removes the need for so meany return statements.

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
    weekend = "06"
    if vacation:
        return "off" if str(day) in weekend else "10:00"
    else:
        return "10:00" if str(day) in weekend else "7:00"
```

---

I would improve it further by adding a check, that you enter a number 0-6.

```
if not (0 <= day <= 6):
    return "-:--"
```

Answer (score 2):

What about:

1. using 10:00 as default:
2. only check for *weekend*
3. you might replace `(str(day) in weekend)` by `(0 == day %6)` but it is harder to understand

Code:

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
    weekend = "06"
    if vacation and (str(day) in weekend):
        return "off"
    else:
        if not (str(day) in weekend):
            return "7:00"
    return "10:00"
```

The bit more cryptic version:

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
    if vacation and 0 == day % 6:
        return "off"
    else:
        if 0 != day % 6:
            return "7:00"
    return "10:00"
```

Comment: `if str(day) not in weekend` would be the preferred construction according to PEP8.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @Joe Wallis' answer, I would shorten it as follows:

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
    weekend = "06"

    times = {"weekend": "10:00", "weekday": "7:00"}
    if vacation:
        times = {"weekend": "off", "weekday": "10:00"}

    return times['weekend'] if str(day) in weekend else times['weekday']
```

Which could be further shortened to (detrimental to readability though):

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
    times = {"weekend": "off", "weekday": "10:00"} if vacation \
            else {"weekend": "10:00", "weekday": "7:00"}

    return times['weekend'] if str(day) in "06" else times['weekday']
```

The advantages are that you have a dict with the weekend/weekday times, so you only need one generic return statement. The magic/hardcoded string in the further shortened version is a no-no though. Furthermore, you could extend the function to allow for custom times to be passed in, as such:

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation, times={}):
    times = times.get('regular', {"weekend": "10:00", "weekday": "7:00"})
    if vacation:
        times = times.get('vacation', {"weekend": "off", "weekday": "10:00"})

    return times['weekend'] if str(day) in "06" else times['weekday']
```

You can then call it as such:

```
times = {'regular': {'weekend': "9:00", "weekday": "7:00"}, "vacation": {"weekend": "12:00", "weekday": "6:00"}}
alarm_clock(2, False, times)
```